# Number format appears to be affecting border format in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm new to Python, and attempting to automate a report at my workplace to save time, space, and trouble. The report runs just fine, and almost all of my code to write the results into an Excel document work as expected as well. However, these two formats:

```
percent = wb.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%','border':1,'border_color':'white'})
integer = wb.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0','border':1,'border_color':'white'})
```

are behaving oddly. When I run this:

```
i = 10
    for lob in report.index.get_level_values(1).unique():
        if report.loc[(program,lob)].sum().sum()==0:
            pass
        else:
            place=report.loc[(program,lob)]
            r=0
            for year in place.index:
                for item in range(8):
                    ws.write(i+r,item+2,place.loc[year][item],integer)
                for item in range(9):
                    ws.write(i+r,item+10,place.loc[year][item+8],percent)
                r+=1
            
            for col_num, value in enumerate(report.columns.values):
                ws.write(i-1, col_num + 2, value, headers)
            ws.write(i-1,1,lob,lobtitle)
            for row_num, year in enumerate(report.index.get_level_values(2).unique()):
                ws.write(i+row_num,1,year,bold)
            ws.set_row(i-1,40)
            ws.set_row(i+7,None,bold)
            i+=10
```

The first eight stats write in my "integer" format with white borders, but the next nine in the row write in percent format for the number, but with no border formatting at all (leaving the default Excel lines). In fact, throughout the report, anything I write with the "integer" format works out, and anything written with the "percent" format gives the correct number format without the border format:

[image]

The apparent simplicity of this issue is driving me crazy. Thanks for any help you can provide.

For reference, here's the full code. 'report' is a multi index dataframe with company programs as level 0, line of business (lob) as level 1, and the years 2015-2020 as level 2.

```
#Establish common formats
wb=xl.Workbook('Report.xlsx')

title=wb.add_format({'font_size':16,'font_name':'Calibri','align':'center','border':1,'border_color':'white'})
subtitle=wb.add_format({'font_size':14,'font_name':'Calibri','align':'center','border':1,'border_color':'white'})
blank=wb.add_format({'bg_color':'white'})
black=wb.add_format({'bg_color':'black'})
bold=wb.add_format({'bold':True,'border_color':'white'})
lobtitle=wb.add_format({'bold':True,'italic':True,'font_size':14})
wrap=wb.add_format({'text_wrap':True})
headers=wb.add_format({'bold':True,'text_wrap':True,'bg_color':'#DCDCDC','align':'center'})
percent = wb.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%','border':1,'border_color':'white'})
integer = wb.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0','border':1,'border_color':'white'})
shadepercent = wb.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%','border':1,'border_color':'white','bg_color':'#DCDCDC'})
shadeinteger = wb.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0','border':1,'border_color':'white','bg_color':'#DCDCDC'})
shadebold=wb.add_format({'bold':True,'border_color':'white','bg_color':'#DCDCDC'})
gridinteger=wb.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0','border':1,'border_color':'gray'})
gridpercent=percent = wb.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%','border':1,'border_color':'gray'})


#For every program, blank out all cells and add company title.

for program in report.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    ws=wb.add_worksheet(program)
    for j in range(100):
        ws.set_row(j,None,blank)
    ws.set_column('B:S',15)
    ws.write(0,10,'Company Title',title)
    ws.write(1,10,'Report Name',subtitle)
    ws.write(2,10,'as of {}'.format(effective),subtitle)
    ws.write(3,10,'Detail',subtitle)
       
#Check each lob within a program for nonzero values. For each nonzero lob, write the lob's stats.
#Write the nonzero lob and its policy years from the index, and drop ten rows for the next entry.
    
    i = 10
    for lob in report.index.get_level_values(1).unique():
        if report.loc[(program,lob)].sum().sum()==0:
            pass
        else:
            place=report.loc[(program,lob)]
            r=0
            for year in place.index:
                for item in range(8):
                    ws.write(i+r,item+2,place.loc[year][item],integer)
                for item in range(9):
                    ws.write(i+r,item+10,place.loc[year][item+8],percent)
                r+=1
            
            for col_num, value in enumerate(report.columns.values):
                ws.write(i-1, col_num + 2, value, headers)
            ws.write(i-1,1,lob,lobtitle)
            for row_num, year in enumerate(report.index.get_level_values(2).unique()):
                ws.write(i+row_num,1,year,bold)
            ws.set_row(i-1,40)
            ws.set_row(i+7,None,bold)
            i+=10
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code isn't complete enough to say what the issue is but there shouldn't be any issue with the formats as this example shows:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data1 = [1000, 1001, 1002]
data2 = [.35, .50, .75]

percent = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%',  'border': 1, 'border_color': 'white'})
integer = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0', 'border': 1, 'border_color': 'white'})

worksheet.write_column(2, 2, data1, integer)
worksheet.write_column(2, 4, data2, percent)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

As a guess the program may be overwriting the percent cells with another format but it isn't possible to tell without a complete working example.

**Update**, based on the update code from the OP:

From your updated code it looks like you are overwriting the percent format here:

```py
gridpercent = percent = wb.add_format(...)
```

This resets the percent format.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've edited my post with the full code for writing these program pages. When I run your code in a new file, it works perfectly. When I copy and paste your formats for integer and percent into mine (just in case I've missed some terribly obvious character somewhere), it fails again.

Comment: From your updated code it looks like you are overwriting the percent format here: `gridpercent=percent = wb.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%','border':1,'border_color':'gray'})`. This resets the percent format.

Comment: Brilliant! I copied the percent format to save trouble and only change the border color, and didn't delete the original format name. Thanks so much!